# Microsoft Graph - add a column index to existing column in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have created a list in SharePoint Online using Microsoft Graph API - I now need to edit one of the columns (the default Title column) and add an index to it. Is there any way to do this through the Graph API? This is possible through CSOM.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked it out - its fairly simple

PATCH [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/columns/{column-id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/lists/%7Blist-id%7D/columns/%7Bcolumn-id%7D)
{
"indexed": "true"
}